# Is python keyboard package available for mac os?

Tags: python, keyboard

I was going to use the python keyboard module to detect a keyboard strike and found that it supports Windows and Linux.
I am curious that this package is updated to support Mac OS now.

Answer (score 0):

The [PyPI page](https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/) for the `keyboard` package, in its 'Feautures' section, states:

> Works with Windows and Linux (requires sudo), with **experimental OS X support** (thanks @glitchassassin!).

So that's a yes, the `keyboard` package has experimental support for MacOS.