# Module Keyboard for MacOs

Tags: python, macos

i want to detect when an key is pressed.
I know the module Keyboard exist for windows but on MacOS it doesn't works

do you know anything who can do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't most systems use an interrupt?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61121796/is-python-keyboard-package-available-for-mac-os

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.